# Getting around symbol favoritism of Simplify and FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

`Simplify` may or may not simplify depending on the symbols you use for its assumptions are good.  For example, here is a case where `Simplify` is uncooperative

```
Simplify[b + c, b + c == a]
(* b + c *)
```

Here is a case where `Simplify` is happy with using the assumptions because it likes `x`, `y` and `z`.

```
Simplify[x + y, x + y == z]
(* z *)
```

Obviously `Simplify` is guilty of symbol favoritism.  How do I formulate the assumptions in `Simplify` so that it will consistently simplify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an old [mathgroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/Jan/msg00237.html) discussion on this. The issue is that `Simplify` uses a Groebner basis and this is dependent on lexical order. The suggestion for getting around this was to use this code from Adam Strzebonski.

```
VOISimplify[vars_, expr_, assum_: True] := Module[{perm, ee, best},
  perm = Permutations[vars];
  ee = (FullSimplify @@ ({expr, assum} /. Thread[vars -> #])) & /@ 
    perm;
  best = Sort[Transpose[{LeafCount /@ ee, ee, perm}]][[1]];
  best[[2]] /. Thread[best[[3]] -> vars]]
```

Then we have

```
VOISimplify[{a, b, c}, b + c, b + c == a]
```

> a

However, checking all lexical orders could be expensive...  I am no expert on this but just remember I had a similar problem in 2005. It is probably time to have further discussions on this issue.

Comment: Nice find on the old mathgroup discussion.  It's too bad you have to manually check for all permutations.

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks for accepting. It might be worth asking a new question to see if there are alternative approaches to the one I found from 2005.  This seems to be a very basic need in computer algebra and there should be a better method rather than looking at all permutations.  I was hoping for a good discussion on the problem but no one seems to have responded to your attractively written question.

Answer (score 1):

In this simple case, converting the equation to a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) and using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) works.

```
b + c /. Rule @@ (b + c == a)

(* a *)
```

or just

```
b + c /. b + c -> a
```

However, it would generally be better to restructure the `Rule` since replacement works better (more consistently) when the LHS of the `Rule` is as simple as possible.

```
b + c /. b -> a - c
```

Or

```
b + c /. c -> a - b
```

Comment: The simple case is the result of isolating the issue in a bigger problem.  The point of using `Simplify` with assumptions is to use transformations to make things simpler.