# Why does side relation work differently in these two cases?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am not able to figure why this replacement using side-relation works in one case but not the other in the following

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, A]
Simplify[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), {x^2 + y^2 == A}]
Simplify[(x + y + z), {x + y == A}]
```

Any idea why it works in one case but not the other?

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It happens the same in version 11.3

Comment: Is this the problem of lexical order?  If you do `Simplify[(a + b + c), {a + b == A}]` you get what you want. See also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179003/12558)

Comment: I honestly don't understand the downvote. In principle, I don't understand any downvote without any explanation, except for cases where it is obvious that there is no effort, or the question is not well posed. Just leaving this comment here. Oh yes, and I upvoted just to fix the situation before reading the question

Comment: Thanks to all answers. All upvoted. I choose bmf's because it had the shortest trick to get it work which I was able to understand. But all answers are great and wish I can accept them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible workaround

```
Simplify[x + y + z, {x + y == Unevaluated[A]}]
```

> [image: res]

Motivated by the answer @Hugh gave I checked the LeafCount, because I thought that it made a difference:

```
LeafCount /@ {x, y, z, A}
LeafCount /@ {x^2 + y^2 + z^2, x^2 + y^2 == A}
LeafCount /@ {x + y + z, x + y == A}
```

> [image: res2]

So, it seems -at least naively- that in the case that Simplify worked properly the expression that is to simplified has greater LeafCount than the assumption.

But, in the workaround which worked that is not the case so this situation seems a bit weird to me.

Comment: The LeafCounts in `Simplify[x*y*z, {x*y == A}]` are the same as in `Simplify[x + y + z, {x + y == A}]` and yet the first one works and not the second. It's the option `MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic` in `PolynomialReduce` that `Simplify` calls internally  that leads to different behavior depending on the degrees of the monomials. I wrote in my answer a section about why I think your answer works.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR**

`Simplify` uses `PolynomialReduce[poly,polyList,variables]` whose output can be sensitive to the order of the elements in `variables`. The order of `variables` is determined by the automatic lexicographic sorting of terms with head `Plus` after applying `Subtract` to the lhs==rhs in the second argument of `Simplify`. Hence, automatic lexicographic sorting of an expression and order sensitivity of `PolynomialReduce` leads `Simplify` to be sensitive to the names of variables.

In the case of `Simplify[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), {x^2 + y^2 == A}]` the simplification still occurs presumably because `PolynomialReduce` uses the option  `MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic` and the degree of A is 1 and so smaller than any other monomial in the expressions above according to `DegreeReverseLexicographic` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Monomials). The name for `A` is then irrelevant due to the lower degree of the monomial and the computation seems to focus on the higher degree monomials like `x^2` and `y^2`.

---

**What went wrong in my previous answer** (can be skipped)

Seems like my previous "not an answer" really was not an answer at all. The major issues in my previous answer was that [`UniqueElements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UniqueElements.html) seemed to not really pick up well on unique elements in a ragged list and the results were not the same the first time and the second time due to Mathematica saving information in the system cache. So I gave `UniqueElements` a better chance by flattening the lists and used [`ClearSystemCache`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearSystemCache.html)[];.

---

#### What happened with `Simplify[(x + y + z), {x + y == A}]` ?

We can now compare:

```
Trace[Simplify[x+y+z,x+y==A],TraceInternal->True]//Flatten
```

with

```
Trace[Simplify[a+b+z,a+b==A],TraceInternal->True]/.{a->x,b->y}//Flatten
```

using

**either**

**Note**: `//Flatten[#,{{2},{1}}]&` is used for transposition of ragged lists see [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/86543)

```
ClearSystemCache[];
(
UniqueElements[
{
Trace[Simplify[a+b+z,a+b==A],TraceInternal->True]/.{a->x,b->y}//Flatten
,
Trace[Simplify[x+y+z,x+y==A],TraceInternal->True]//Flatten
}
]
//Map[Map[Column[{#,ReleaseHold@#},Dividers->Center]&]]
//Flatten[#,{{2},{1}}]&
//Part[#,1;;19]&
//Grid[#,Frame->All]&
)
```

(**I explain the important parts below** if you want to skip looking at the table)

> Below:
>
> Comparison of the differences between the traces of
> `Simplify[x+y+z,x+y==A]` (on the right) and `Simplify[a+b+z,a+b==A]`
> (on the left) after substituting `a` with `x` and `b` with `y` in the
> trace. Each line corresponds to a step Mathematica takes in the
> computation. Each line contains a horizontal delimiter with code in
> `HoldForm` and its evaluation at the bottom.

[image]

**or** if you rather see the original `a` and `b` on the left

```
ClearSystemCache[];
(
UniqueElements[
{
Trace[Simplify[a+b+z,a+b==A],TraceInternal->True]/.{a->x,b->y}//Flatten
,
Trace[Simplify[x+y+z,x+y==A],TraceInternal->True]//Flatten
}
]
//MapAt[ReplaceAll[{x->a,y->b}],#,1]&
//Map[Map[Column[{#,ReleaseHold@#},Dividers->Center]&]]
//Flatten[#,{{2},{1}}]&
//Part[#,1;;19]&
//Grid[#,Frame->All]&
)
```

[image]

The important points above are :

- the difference in ordering of the additions and substraction due to how Mathematica sorts variables in a sum of terms according to `Sort[variables]` (recall that before the substitution {a->x,b->y} in the trace of evaluations, a,b,z,A was used in one case and x,y,z,A in the other as shown explicitly in the steps below)
- the usage of [`PolynomialReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce.html). We will **not** get into the details of this function.

We can simulate the steps of `Simplify` below:

- **Step 1** : turn the second argument of `Simplify` lhs==rhs to lhs-rhs for polynomial reduction in step 2

so

```
Subtract @@ (a + b == A )
(* a - A + b *)

Subtract @@ (x + y == A)
(* -A + x + y *)
```

**Step 2** : polynomial substitution

The documentation for [`PolynomialReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce.html) shows that `PolynomialReduce` can be used to

> Replace variables in a polynomial using equations relating old and new
> variables

This is what `Simplify` uses. The documentation for `PolynomialReduce` and `Simplify` use `GroebenerBasis` as an intermediate but this does not seem important for the explanation of why the substitution does not occur in the example given by OP.

- **Sub-step 1**: get the variables for the substitution

The variables are obtained using:

```
Variables[a-A+b]
(* {a,A,b} *)

Variables[-A+x+y]
(* {A,x,y} *)
```

**Sub-step 2**: substitute polynomials using `PolynomialReduce`

The syntax below is:

> PolynomialReduce[expression to simplify, {left hand side of step 1
> (the constraint)}, variables from sub-step
> 1,MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]

compare :

```
PolynomialReduce[a+b+z,{a-A+b},{a,A,b},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{1},A+z} *)
```

with :

```
PolynomialReduce[x+y+z,{A-x-y},{A,x,y},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{0},x+y+z} *)
```

Why did `PolynomialReduce` fail ?

Is it the A-x-y instead of x-A+y ?

```
PolynomialReduce[x+y+z,{x-A+y},{A,x,y},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{0},x+y+z} *)
```

No, it's actually just the order of the variables `{A,x,y}` found using `Variables[-A+x+y]` previously.

With the automatic ordering of variables within an expression with head `Plus`, that is the same order of variables as `Sort[{x,A,y}]`.

To show that the problem is the order of the variables, we can change the order of the variables to

`{x,A,y}`

```
PolynomialReduce[x+y+z,{A-x-y},{x,A,y},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{-1},A+z} *)
```

or

```
PolynomialReduce[x+y+z,{A-x-y},{x,y,A},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{-1},A+z} *)
```

It seems that when all monomials have the same degree, `PolynomialReduce` tries the polynomial replacement by substituting the first variable in the variable list. As `A` is not present in `x+y+z` nothing happens. To reinforce this possibility compare:

```
PolynomialReduce[x+y+2*A,{-A-x-y},{A,y,x},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{-2},-x-y} *)

PolynomialReduce[x+2*y+A,{-A-x-y},{y,A,x},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{-2},-A-x} *)
```

where we notice that the first variable is systematically substituted.

---

#### Why did `Simplify` work with `Simplify[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), {x^2 + y^2 == A}]` ?

First notice that if we do not specify MonomialOrder, then we have the same problem as before where the result depends on the order of list of variables in the third argument:

```
PolynomialReduce[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {-A + x^2 + y^2}, 
  { A,x, y}]
(* {{0},x^2+y^2+z^2} *)

PolynomialReduce[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {-A + x^2 + y^2}, 
  { x,A, y}]
(* {{1},A+z^2} *)
```

This behavior seems to be overridden when one specifies MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic in which case A is smaller than any other monomial in the expressions above (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order#Monomials). The name of A is then irrelevant but not necessarily the names of `x` and `y`. To see why consider:

```
PolynomialReduce[
  -x^2 + y^2 + z^2+A, {-A + x^2 + y^2}, 
  {A,x,y},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{-1},2 y^2+z^2} *)

PolynomialReduce[
  -x^2 + y^2 + z^2+A, {-A + x^2 + y^2}, 
  {x,A,y},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{-1},2 y^2+z^2} *)

PolynomialReduce[
   -x^2 + y^2 + z^2+A, {-A + x^2 + y^2}, 
  {x,y,A},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{-1},2 y^2+z^2} *)

PolynomialReduce[
  -x^2 + y^2 + z^2+A, {-A + x^2 + y^2}, 
  {y,x,A},MonomialOrder->DegreeReverseLexicographic]
(* {{1},2 A-2 x^2+z^2} *)
```

---

#### Why does **Unevaluated** work in the answer by @bmf ?

I am not sure about the details because of the usage of Unevaluated which could affect some of the internal computations but here is the trace comparison:

```
ClearSystemCache[];
(
UniqueElements[
{
Trace[Simplify[x+y+z,x+y==Unevaluated@A],TraceInternal->True]/.HoldPattern[Unevaluated@A]->A//Flatten
,
Trace[Simplify[x+y+z,x+y==A],TraceInternal->True]//Flatten
}
]
//MapAt[ToExpression@*StringReplace["A"->"Unevaluated@A"]@*ToString@*InputForm,#,1]&
//Map[Map[Column[{#,Evaluate@ReleaseHold@#},Dividers->Center]&]]
//Flatten[#,{{2},{1}}]&

//Part[#,1;;23]&
//Grid[#,Frame->All]&
)
```

[image]

It seems that `Unevaluated` works because :

```
Sort[{x,A,Unevaluated@A,Unevaluated@B,a,b,Infinity,_}]
(* {a,A,b,x,_,∞,Unevaluated[A],Unevaluated[B]} *)
```

So `Unevaluated@A` was the rightmost variable in the list of variables given to `PolynomialReduce`. There could be more subtleties I am not sure.

---

#### Previous "answer"

**Not an answer** just an extended comment/exploration:

---

**TL;DR**

TraceInternal shows some differences that might be linked to the presence of DegreeReverseLexicographic in the trace but the output from trace does not seem to explain why there is a difference. The problem seems deeper than what TraceInternal shows.

---

We can compare some of the differences of what Mathematica is doing depending on the choice of variables using TraceInternal and [`UniqueElements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UniqueElements.html) (Mathematica version 13.1).

There is very little difference and so I imagine the root of the problem is even deeper than what TraceInternal shows. This is shown by how the same change in symbols for the power case does not change the result.

As mentioned, the difference in the traces below might be related to lexicographic order which is hinted on at the end but it does not explain really where the problem is.

Consider first the linear case:

```
l1 = Trace[Simplify[(a + b + z), {a + b == A}], 
   TraceInternal -> True];

l2 = Trace[Simplify[(x + y + z), {x + y == A}], 
   TraceInternal -> True];
```

To compare the two lists we change `a` with `x` and `b` with `y` after obtaining `l1`:

```
l1Mod = l1 /. {a -> x, b -> y};
```

Now we can check what is unique to each trace:

```
UniqueElements[{l1Mod, l2}] // Map[Map[MatrixForm]] // 
  Map[Column] // Row
```

[image]

The reason for the partially different elements seems related to :

```
Select[TextWords[ToString@InputForm@l2], 
StringContainsQ["exicogra"]] // DeleteDuplicates
```

`(* {"DegreeReverseLexicographic"} *)`

In the power case using `a` and `b` instead of `x` and `y` the difference between the outputs is similar and yet somehow the results are the same which may contradict some conclusions from the linear case (the final outputs are not shown because they are the same):

[image]

I did not notice much of a different in the case of power expressions when compared to the linear case.

The following shows a list of the functions that were called and that are shown in TraceInternal:

**Note**: Below there is a change of notation where `l1Mod=lab•linear•xy` and `lab•power•xy` is the equivalent of `lab•linear•xy` for the power/square case.

• List of functions called in the trace for the power case (x^2+y^+z^2 and x^2+y^2=A):

```
e = Cases[lab•power•xy, h_[___] :> h, All] // 
  DeleteDuplicates

(* {Power, Plus, Equal, List, Simplify, HoldForm, N, Floor, Mod, Times, 
 Ceiling, And, MessageName, Off, Expand, PolynomialQ, Set, Blank, 
 Integrate`FakeIntervalElement, Sequence, RuleDelayed, ReplaceAll, 
 FactorList, Sign, Variables, Rule, GroebnerBasis, Flatten, 
 Solve`SolvVar, Together, On, $Off} *)
```

• List of functions called in the trace for the linear case (x+y+z and x+y=A)

```
j = Cases[lab•linear•xy, h_[___] :> h, All] // 
  DeleteDuplicates

(* {Plus, Equal, List, Simplify, HoldForm, N, Floor, Mod, Times, Ceiling, 
 And, MessageName, Off, Expand, PolynomialQ, Set, Blank, 
 Integrate`FakeIntervalElement, Sequence, RuleDelayed, ReplaceAll, 
 FactorList, Power, Sign, Variables, Rule, GroebnerBasis, Flatten, 
 Solve`SolvVar, Together, On, $Off} *)
```

Other than the order and maybe some duplicates (I did not compare duplicates) the functions called are the same :

```
UniqueElements[{e, j}]
```

`(* {{}, {}} *)`

Comment: Very good detective work -well done. I have not seen a more detailed account before.  What are your conclusions regarding the workings of `VOISimplify` in my post? Does this work or are there still some problems in that approach?

Comment: @Hugh Thank you I spent an unreasonable amount of time trying to understand what was going on haha. I had left a comment about `VOISimplify` below your answer as one of the duplicates in the link you gave shows an example where it did not work https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83756/86543. However, I could not reproduce the problem with `FullSimplify` in Mathemtica 13.1 so I left it alone. That example uses `!=`. I am not sure how Simplify handles `!=`.  A priori, I see no reason why `VOISimplify` would not work when the second argument of `Simplify` involves only `==`. But trying ...

Comment: ... all permutations sounds very costly. Knowing or testing `PolynomialReduce` and knowing Lexicographic order seems sufficient for avoiding the surprises I checked so far on small expressions. Not sure about big expressions.

Comment: Basically knowing that the smallest variable in terms of lexicographic order might get substituted into the expression first unless it has a low degree. And that if that lowest variable is not immediately present then nothing happens.

Comment: bmf's Unevaluated solution seems like a good way to make sure a desired variable appears in the expression as it will be the last variable `PolynomialReduce` tries but I am at unease with how `Simplify` might handle the `Unevaluated` in the general case. Using a variable like `ZZ` and then using `/.ZZ->A` for example feels safer. I think `SolveValues[Eliminate[{g == x + y + z, x + y == A}, {x, y}], g][[1]]` is more reliable then one can use `Simplify` after that with no second argument in a more complicated expression.

Comment: But Daniel Lichblau mentioned that `Eliminate` uses old technology so it might not be that reliable.

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete answer but may be part of the problem. Is this a problem of lexical order? See also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179003/12558).

If you do

```
Simplify[(a + b + c), {a + b == A}]
```

You get

```
(* A + c *)
```

If you use this code from Adam Strzebonski see previous post

```
  VOISimplify[vars_, expr_, assum_ : True] := 
     Module[{perm, ee, best}, perm = Permutations[vars];
      ee = (FullSimplify @@ ({expr, assum} /. Thread[vars -> #])) & /@ 
        perm;
      best = Sort[Transpose[{LeafCount /@ ee, ee, perm}]][[1]];
      best[[2]] /. Thread[best[[3]] -> vars]]
```

you get what you need

```
VOISimplify[{x, y, z, A}, (x + y + z), x + y == A]
```

output

```
 (*  A + z *)
```

I am just showing my age because I raised this on [mathgroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/Jan/msg00237.html) in 2005.
The code is rather too complex for me to work out what is happening but you may be able to sort this out. Hope that helps.