# "Simplify" with conditions not giving the expected result

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am using Mathematica for a long calculation, while performing checks throughout the code. I noticed that the following is not working as I expected and is resulting in inconsistencies later on.

```
Simplify[(b + c)/a, {a + b + c == 0}, Assumptions -> {Reals[a, b, c], a != 0, b != 0, c != 0}]

(* Out: (b + c)/a *)
```

I have also tried `FullSimplify` and `Refine`, but nothing seems to return the answer $-1$. Can someone point out what needs to be added/changed to obtain the expected result and/or why this does not automatically `Simplify` to $-1$?

I suspect there is a similar problem in the following as well:

```
FullSimplify[
  (b/c)^n/a^n - (b/(a*c))^n, 
  Assumptions -> {
    Reals[a, b, c], Integers[n], 
    a != 0, b != 0, c != 0, 
    n > 1
  }
]

(* Out: (b/c)^n/a^n - (b/(a*c))^n *)
```

I am using Mathematica 12.2

Comment: Your second FullSimplify simply suffers from a syntax error: `Reals` is a domain, not a function, so you should write `Element[{a, b, c}, Reals]` instead of `Reals[a, b, c]`. The latter means nothing. With those changes, the expression simplifies to zero.

Answer (score 3):

side relation is little tricky. See [Why does side relation work differently in these two cases?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277607/why-does-side-relation-work-differently-in-these-two-cases)

For your case it works if you do this

```
ClearAll[a, b, c]
Simplify[(b + c)/a, {b + c == -Unevaluated[a]}]
(* -1 *)
```

Compare to

```
Simplify[(b + c)/a, {b + c == -a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And

```
Simplify[(b + c)/a, {b + c + a == 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

For the first case:

```
(b + c)/a /. b -> -a - c
```

or any equivalent phrasal of the relation should suffice.

---

For the second case:

```
expr = (b/c)^n/(a)^n - (b/(a*c))^n
```

`PowerExpand[expr]` gives `0`.

or try:

```
Simplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PowerExpand}]
```

or improve syntax:

```
Simplify[expr, 
 Assumptions -> {{a, b, c} ∈ Reals, n ∈ Integers, 
   a != 0, b != 0, c != 0, n > 1}]
```